# js cookie is not saving

Tags: javascript, cookies

I was trying to save cookie using document.cookie="name=value;" in js, yet when I alert the document.cookie right after I set it, nothing showed on the screen, it seemed like the cookie was not saved at all. I'm using Chrome.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function setRole(role){

        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + 24*3600*1000);
        document.cookie = "role=" + role + ";expires=" + date.toGMTString();
        alert("cookie=" + document.cookie);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: How are you accessing your index.html? I mean on the browser, how does the url looks like?

Comment: If "nothing showed on screen", you either didn't invoke the function or your code broke down and you have an error in your console.

Comment: Yes @Amadan is right, check the console for errors.

Comment: Also may I know why you want to use cookie?